# object and array schemas. When to use?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, database-schema

Trying to figure out my database schema.

When to use objects and when to use arrays? What's the best practice? I found it confusing since I don't have much experience.

Here I'm trying to put some sample data to my react app state:

```
module.exports = {

    expense1: [
      {
        date: 'some date 1',
        description: 'some description 1',
        amount: '123'
      },{
        date: 'some date 1',
        description: 'some description 1',
        amount: '123'
      },{
        date: 'some date 1',
        description: 'some description 1',
        amount: '123'
      }
    ],


    expense2: [
      {
        date: 'some date 1',
        description: 'some description 1',
        amount: '123'
      },{
        date: 'some date 1',
        description: 'some description 1',
        amount: '123'
      }
    ]

};
```

each expense has many expense items.

Does this schema make sense?

Where should I put unique ids?

I'm going to use firebase database for this app.

There has to be CRUD functionality for a user. A user should be able to see clickable expense list i.e expense1 and expense2. When he clicks on it he should be redirected to that specific expense and CRUD its items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually I tenb to use array when there is an order in the elements. It will help you using sort function for instances and many others.

But if you have only a elements to store then an object with properties as objectId is perfect, there is no need to use something else :)

Comment: Hm. Thanks for your answer. So does this schema looks ok? Do I need to add unique IDs for my each expense item? i.e `{ id: uuid(),
      date: 'some date 1',
      description: 'some description 1',
      amount: '123'
    },`

Comment: It depends what you need to do with that object when you use it, but if you just need to add data to your database then the ID will be managed by your database manager. If you need to retrieve data from your database then the id can be your property name

Comment: From UI perspective there has to be CRUD functionality for a user. A user should be able to see clickable expense list i.e expense1 and expense2. When he clicks on it he should be redirected to that specific expense and CRUD its items.

Comment: Therefore I think that you can stay with your object as I don't see the point having an array as you just need to have data identified by an id :)